# POST requests to Bing Webmaster API always gives NotAuthorized

Tags: post, seo, sitemap, bing, bing-webmaster-tools

I'm trying to programmatically submit sitemap index files to Bing via HTTP POST requests.
I followed the JSON request example from their [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554139.aspx).

Here is the request I'm trying to make in cURL (I replaced the site url and apikey):

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Host: ssl.bing.com' -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{
"siteUrl":"https:\/\/www.example.com",
"feedUrl":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/Sitemaps\/SitemapIndex--stuff--01.xml"
}' 'https://bing.com/webmaster/api.svc/json/SubmitFeed?apikey=MY_KEY'
```

The response looks like this:

```
{
    "ErrorCode": 14,
    "Message": "ERROR!!! NotAuthorized"
}
```

The api key is generated from the Bing [webmaster ui portal](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/home/api). My user has `administrator` rights. Adding a Content-Length header did not help.

GET requests work alright and I can retrieve feed or traffic information.

In the Bing webmaster portal UI page I can submit sitemap files with no problem.

I've searched the web for this before asking and I could not find anything relevant. Has anyone encountered this problem also? Probably I'm missing something and I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: Running into the same issue. Did you figure it out eventually?

Comment: @stepanian Nope.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears when:

1 - Verified URL in the webmaster does not match **siteUrl** in your request

Example:
webmaster - https://example.com/
request - https://example.com/home

2 - URL's in your **urlList** does not match **siteUrl** pattern

Example:
**siteUrl** - https://example.com/home/
**url** - https://example.com/about-us.html